# From Java to C#: storing couple of int using Dimension

Tags: c#, java, xna

Usually in Java when I need to store 2 int value related to some graphic properties I use Dimension Object:

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(x,y);
```

Is there any similar object in C# (and XNA)? I'm currently using Vector2 but it's designed for floating values.
Actually I need such a structure to create a list of screen coordinates. I'm looking for something to use this way:

```
IList<Dimension> list = new List<Dimension>();
list.add(new Dimension(800,600));
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.point.aspx):

> Defines a point in 2D space.

```
IList<Point> list = new List<Point>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some additional info since this was tagged as XNA as well - in XNA if you want to store X,Y locations (or any other set of two related variables) you probably want to use Vector2 instead of Point. If it's not XNA, Point is exactly what you want.

Just a gotcha about Vector2 though - it's floats and not ints. You can cast the values when you retreive them if you want ints - though if you're feeding them to other XNA functions, they'll likely expect floats anyway making a cast unnecessary.